# Small tool icons in programs.(Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ide, codeblocks

Small toolbar icons:

[image: (small toolbar icons image)]

So I have the same problem like this person (https://superuser.com/questions/1277089/icons-in-all-of-programs-are-very-small-windows-10) but I have Ubuntu where you cannot just do the same like in instructions to previous person problem. I am using Code::Blocks IDE and I literally see nothing (too small icons) when I compile and look at terminal output.

So, this is how compiler output looks like.

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: We are talking about font size, i.e. characters or glyphs, don't we? (I wondered a bit about "Small tool icons" when I embedded your image.) You should change the font setting of your console. (No idea how to do it in Code Blocks. When I used *ix systems years ago, there were resource files which could be customized if necessary.) Maybe, try [google "codeblocks console font size"](https://www.google.com/search?q=codeblocks+console+font+size). The outcome looked promising but I didn't dig deeper.

Comment: What icons? I can't see any icons in the image. Do you mean the font size?

Comment: I just found an answer to Code::Blocks IDE console output font size but it is more connected with Xterm (which is an output window) and changed the font size which really helped me but the actual size of tool bars is making me sad of its size too. It actually is adjustable but not as much as it should be in order to be readable.

Comment: UPD: added a link to a picture of small icons in Code::Blocks IDE.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to sharpen your google skills. ;-) [google "code blocks icon size"](https://www.google.com/search?q=code+blocks+icon+size). First (!) hit is [Icon are too small on a 2k monitor](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=21724.0) in the Code::Blocks forum.

Comment: Scheff, I know about the standard adjust of the toolbar (Settings -> Environment), which is just a little bit small font size for my eyes (bad eyesight). However, I just fixed the whole problem and I installed Qt Creator that seems to be better. Nevertheless, thanks for giving advice to google more than I do each day.